# Creating server - handle CORS pre-flighted

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, server, cors

I'm creating a server to my online minesweeper game, and I have to deal with login info. I'm sending the information from the client in a JSON object and I'm now trying to parse it. However, I receive the message with the method "OPTIONS". I know this is pre-flighted CORS and I understand the reasons behind it, but my question is: how do I handle this request, respond to client "Ok, you are allowed to send your "POST"" and parse it, so that I can register people in database. Can someone help? Thanks in advance and a happy new year to everyone!

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var http = require('http'); // 
var url = require('url');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'}); //server responde  'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
handle(request); // function to handle the reques

}).listen(8020);

console.log("Listen on port 8020 boy...");


function handle(request){

    console.log(request.url);
    console.log(request.method);

     if (request.url === '/register') {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(request, function (err, fields, files) {
        register(fields);
     });
    }
}

function register(fields){
    console.log("Requested login/register. Here are the fields");
    console.log(fields);
    //gotoDB();
}

function gotoDB(){
    var conn = mysql.createConnection({

    host : 'localhost', // Connecting to DB..
    user : 'user',
    password : 'UWish',
    database : 'school'
});

}
```

Comment: Beware: origin:'*' cannot be used together with Authroization header. Below example is correctly using a specific origin

Comment: Also, as for the client you must specify allowCredentials = true to the XMLHttpRequest - otherwise cookies are not transmitter along with cors

Answer (score 2):

You got the idea right, mostly. Here is what I typically use:

```
// CORS
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var origin = req.get('Origin')

  if (!origin) {
    return next()
  }

  if ((origin.indexOf('https://example.com') > 0)) {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin)
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT')
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization')
  }

  if (req.method.toLowerCase() === 'options') {
    return res.sendStatus(200)
  }

  next()
})
```

*I just noticed you're using vanilla Node.js and not Express.* You should probably look into either that or at least Connect middleware, it helps a lot in making a well-structured app and is fairly simple to grasp.

Comment: thanks ! In your example, you're using Connect, right?

Comment: Express, but yes the middleware concept comes from Connect.